# How to patch a function in pytest, registered on sqlalchemy event.listen "after_update"?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mocking, pytest

I have a function which is registered as an event on a sqlalchemy model, as show in the code snippets below (not fully-functional as I don't show the `db` fixture), which should be enough to explain the problem.

> root/myapp/models.py:

```
class MyModel:
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    value = ''

    @classmethod
    def register_hook(cls, hook_fn):
        event.listen(cls, "after_update", hook_fn, propagate=True)
```

> root/myapp/app.py:

```
from models import MyModel

def hook_fn(mapper, connection, target):
    print('fired hook!')

MyModel.register_hook(hook_fn)
```

> root/test/conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture
def patched_hook_fn(mocker):
    with mocker.patch("root.myapp.app.hook_fn") as patched:
        yield patched
```

> root/test/tests.py:

```
def test_hook_fires_on_change(db, patched_hook_fn):
    model = MyModel(value="initial")
    db.session.commit()
    model.value = "changed"
    db.session.commit()  # hook fires here
    assert patched_hook_fn.called  # assert fails
```

What I'd like to know is:

1. Why doesn't the patched function get called?
2. Is there a simple way in a debug session to see where I should be patching in the `with mocker.patch("myapp.app.hook_fn") as patched` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get called because you've already registered the unpatched version with the event system. SQLAlchemy does not read the value at `root.myapp.app.hook_fn` every time the event is fired, so even if you later set `root.myapp.app.hook_fn = some_other_function` (which is what `patch` is doing), it has no visible effect.

The way to fix this is to simply force your app to read the value every time the event is fired, by introducing a level of indirection:

```
MyModel.register_hook(lambda: hook_fn())
```

This takes advantage of the way Python resolves identifiers in a closure, where changing `root.myapp.app.hook_fn` actually changes the value of `hook_fn` in the closure.

As for your second question, there's no straightforward way to figure out what you need to patch because in order to patch it directly you need to figure out where it is stored in the internals of SQLAlchemy, and depending on that, even in your tests, is quite fragile.